# how to avoid my app from starting automatically when i start facebook app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication, logout

i created an app where users can log in via facebook login button. the problem is - whenever i start the facebook app on the phone, it automatically starts the other app, too and logs the user in. any idea how to avoid this? 
here is my login action for facebook:

```
fbLoginButton.setReadPermissions("user_friends");

    // Callback registration

    fbLoginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            // App code
            Log.v("STATUS", loginResult.getAccessToken().toString());
            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                    loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(
                                JSONObject object,
                                GraphResponse response) {

                            Log.e("response: ", response + "");
                            try {
                                String facebookID = object.getString("id").toString();
                                String email = object.getString("email").toString();
                                String name = object.getString("name").toString();
                                //PrefUtils.setCurrentUser(user,LoginActivity.this);

                                String[] nameArray = name.split(" ");
                                String firstname = nameArray[0];
                                String lastname = nameArray[1];
                                Log.v("FIRSTNAME", firstname);

                                if(response.getError() == null) {
                                   new FBLogin().execute(email, firstname, lastname, facebookID);
                                }

                                Log.v("FBEMAIL", object.toString());
                            }catch (Exception e){
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                    });
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            // App code
            Log.v("im in", "2");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            // App code
            Log.v("im in", "3");
        }
    });

// catches fb login callback
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Do i have to log the user out in some special way with my logout button? till now on logout it just redirects back to my main activity and the user has to logout manually by clicking on the fb button. i'm confused and google couldn't help me out yet...

Comment: Facebook app start, and then another app start too and try FB login? What app is it?

Comment: When launch facebook app your apps starts too? are you listening any kind of intent action? check in your manifest its sounds fissy to me..

Comment: what exactly do you mean by check in your manifest? what should i check?